# Python/Mako: Script Tag not showing up from Sub Template when Loaded into Main Template via Ajax Call

Tags: python, ajax, include, pyramid, mako

I basically have a 3 level template.
I want to load dynamically load a script tag from a sub template into the main template.

Template Setup:

- A Base page with all the headers/scripts
- 2nd level template which contains the new script tag and loads a widget
- 3rd level template which contains the widget

All I'm trying to do is when the 3rd level template is loaded, load a specific javascript file, so I don't have a heavy filled up head tag on my base template with javascript files which may not get used.

**Base Template (in the head tag):**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
${next.javascriptIncludes()}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/modules/baseModule.js"></script>
```

**2nd Template *(Where the script tag is)***

```
##conditional to determine if the template should inherit from the base page
##it shouldn't inherit from the base page if it is being inserted into the page using ajax
<%!
def inherit(context):
    if context.get('isPage'):
        return "base_dashboard.mak"
    else:
        return None
%>
<%inherit file="${inherit(context)}"/>

<%def name="javascriptIncludes()">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/libs/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</%def>

## AJAX load
%if isPage is False:
    blah blah blah shows up
    <script>s</script>
    <h1>H1 shows up</h1>
    <p style="color:red;">P tag shows up in red</p>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css"><- This shows up
    <div><script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/libs/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min.js"></script></div>
    Script tag above is missing...
%endif

<div id="dashboard-profile-container">
<%include file="widgets/profile_widget.mak" />
</div>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**3rd Template (The Widget)**

```
Just HTML
```

**Issue:** Script tag is NOT getting included in the header of the Base template

How would you handle this problem?

Comment: What is "next" in this context? It is indeed a builtin python function and you should avoid name collisions. Can't you use a different name?

Comment: You are right, I'm not inheriting anything, so not needing to use NEXT... updating Question with new info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that jQuery evaluates *and strips* all `<script>` tags from a HTML fragment loaded with AJAX, although at the moment I can't find a proof of that in jQuery docs:

> "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated
>   when inserted in the DOM.

However, here is is [in John Resig's own words](http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/jQuery-domManip-script-tag-will-be-removed-td151107.html):

> When a script node is inserted into the document it is also executed
>   (by jQuery). To avoid re-executing it later (this happens a lot, as it
>   turns out) the script is simply removed from the document.
>
> Naturally, this causes some issues when you actually want to see the
>   contents of the script element (as you do). However I think the
>   trade-off is better in this case.
>
> The one alternative solution that I can think of is to use the
>   internal .data() API to attach information to the script element,
>   informing it that shouldn't be executed again at a later time. I'm not
>   sure how unexpected that is, though.

so, at least, jQuery used to strip `<script>` tags in 2009.

To verify you can use Firebug etc. to confirm that your application indeed returns a HTML blob with the `<script>` tag included - if you confirm this then it's totally not related to Pyramid of Mako

Comment: Ah! In our loadResource (load template) function I'm using this: 'var $content = $($.parseHTML(response.trim()));' that must strip out the script tags. Hmm I believe we're looking into Require.js now for a better solution. Thanks as it currently stands we can't use the above code to solve our current problem.

Comment: To others with similar questions, this is what we're going to use: http://requirejs.org

Answer (score 2):

Next is the next template in the inheritance chain.  There isn't a naming conflict. The second template does an include, so next is null (there isn't a third layer in the inheritance chain).  Hence, object has no attribute.